# Visual Studio. How to temporarily open a file with a single click

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

If I double click on a file in the Visual Studio Solution Explorer (VS2019), it is opened for editing in a new tab on the far left of the tab area. If I double click on another it too is opened in a new tab on the left.
In the past, I have been able to single click on a file and it was shown in a tab that displayed on the far right of the tabs area. If I single clicked on another file, it would replace the text of the first file in the same tab. I could keep doing this and each file was opened temporarily in that same tab. If I edited what was in that tab, it was moved to the left tab area and remained opened even if I single clicked on another file that appeared in a tab on the right.
This was super convenient for when I just wanted to look at a file without editing it any. Could you tell me how to do this? I looked through the configuration settings and didn't see anything. It would be super helpful for reviewing some of the hundreds of new files I need to look at in a new project I am taking over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The setting you are looking for is `Preview selected files in Solution Explorer`. It can be found in the `Environment -> Tabs and Windows -> Preview Tab` settings page:

[image]

After turning it on, clicking on a file once in the Solution Explorer will "preview the file" (which is the official name of the feature) in a special preview tab.

Comment: Thank you much. That is going to be a big help. I did look there but did not realize that I would need to select the "Preview Selected Files in Solution Explorer" to get it to work.

Comment: Cheers @Miguelito. If the answer solved your problem, please remember to mark it as the correct answer.